# a route with several optional parameters

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular controller presenting data with the ability to filter.
Now I need several optional filter parameters. Example:

```
http://esample.org/inquiries/
http://esample.org/inquiries/3/
http://esample.org/inquiries/3/answered
http://esample.org/inquiries/answered
```

- The first url would show all inquiries,
- the second all inquiries for accommodation #1,
- the third all answered inquiries for the accommodation #1 and
- the fourth all answered inquiries.

Can I define a url in ui-router that matches all three urls?
How can I define multiple, optional, additional parameters?

I tried adding the slash as an optional parameter but it didn't match.

```
.state('inquiries', {
    url: "/inquiries/{accommodationId:[0-9]*}{slash:[/]*}{inquiriesType:[a-z]*}",
    templateUrl: "views/inquiries.html",
    controller: "InquiriesController",
    [...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LcLKE1VO4gr1s4mYttN?p=preview) with a little bit adjusted url defintion:

```
url: "/inquiries/{accommodationId:[0-9]*}{slash:[/]?}{inquiriesType:[a-z]*}",
```

All these *(using '#' here)* are working then:

```
<a href="#/inquiries/">
<a href="#/inquiries/3/">
<a href="#/inquiries/3/answered">
<a href="#/inquiries/answered">
```

See that in action [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/4LcLKE1VO4gr1s4mYttN?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have been able to figure that out myself, using `?` rather than `*` :)